# Worklight Push Notification best approach - Push or Poll

Tags: notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, push, polling

I'm new to mobile/worklight app development. I would like to know the best approach for push notification. Trigger the notification from backend whenever some change happens or polling in regular interval of time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best approach". There is "what fits best your needs".

Since you did not actually explain those needs, what you *can* do is review the following to get a better grasp of your possibilities and potential topologies for push notifications, as well as an overview and pros & cons.

- User documentation topic: [Push Notifications overview](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_push_notification.html)
- Blog post: [Worklight Push Notification Possible Architectures](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_push_notification_possible_architectures?lang=en)

If you decide on a polling approach, you can also [read this blog post on polling](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_a_polling_event_source_to_send_push_notifications?lang=en).